# CSS How to make div 100% despite 80% div

Tags: html, css, width

I want to make the width of a div (divTwo) inside of another div (divOne) 100% width despite the 80% width of divOne. Is this possible?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u3mbjgp3/

HTML:

```
<div class="divOne">
    <div class="divTwo"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.divOne {
    width: 80%;
    height: 250px;
    background: #00ff00; /*green*/
}

.divTwo {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    background: #000; /*black*/
}
```

Comment: you want it to extend over the bounds of `divOne` ?

Comment: Well, it is 100% the width of its parent which is 80% the width of its parent.

Comment: Sorry I meant 100% screen width despite the 80% width of divOne

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want `divTwo` to take 100% of window width you can use `100vw`

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  height: 0;
}
.divOne {
  width: 80%;
  height: 250px;
  background: #00ff00;
}
.divTwo {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 150px;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="divOne">
  <div class="divTwo"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked... well sorta... still have a small problem now xD: https://i.gyazo.com/1758e3b70423baf18a1a4e8c5b444c3a.png

Comment: Try adding `* { box-sizing: border-box}`

Comment: If your parent element have margin or padding you will have to use same amount of negative margin/padding on child element  https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1320/